# setInterval causing a memory overflow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

For the record, I am using the Node API for a lot of my programming. Anyway, when I run my code I get a memory leak error, saying that there are 11 emitters open. If this is the case, how would I prevent my program from opening up several instances of getData? If I cannot prevent that, is there a crude way to delete instances that I don't want emitted? I am trying to run the function every 50 ms.
Here is my code:

```
setInterval(getData, 100);

function getData() {
    "use strict";
    //When the serialport opens:
    serialport.on("open", function() {
        serialport.on("data", function(data) {
            //Takes the current string value, turns it into an integer, then stores it in nCurrentValue
            runData( parseInt(data.toString()) );
        });
    });
}
getData();

function runData(value) {
    "use strict";
    socket.emit('NewData',value);
    console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: well, you are adding the event triggers for onopen and ondata every 100 ms seconds, so i guess, after a while it floods yes...

Comment: As suggested by @Icepickle, why do you need the `setInterval` at all? This appears to be event driven and will call the `runData` method every time you receive data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by extracting the event triggers outside of your getData. As far as I understand nodejs, it is event driven, so you should only attach the onopen / ondata once, and all connections will then come over your function calls.

I guess you only need to do the following:

```
serialport.on("open", newConnection);
serialport.on("data", newDataReceived);

function newConnection() {
    // do something with the connection...
}

function newDataReceived(data) {
    // do something with the data received
}
```

i'm guessing, that the serial port also sends info when the connection gets closed, so you could add something in the likes of:

```
serialport.on("close", closeConnection);

function closeConnection() {
    // close the connection internally afterwards
}
```

although the last part is a pure guess...

in this case, nodejs should fire the open event when a new connection is made, and afterwards, fire the data event when data is received. If you would check which library you are using for the serialport, there might be a guide on how to use the library